# Complex numbers

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

If someone could help me with this question I would really appreciate it.For some reason I am getting a weaker version of these inequalities when applying triangle inequality.

Let S be the interior of the circle |z − 1 − i| = 1.
that if z ∈ S then √5 − 1 < |z − 3| < √5 + 1.
Obtain the result geometrically by considering the line containing the center of the circle and the point 3.

Answer (score 0):

Using triangle inequality: If $z \in S$ then $|z - 3| = |z - 1 - i + i - 2| < |z - 1 - i| + 
|i - 2|  < 1 + \sqrt{5}$

$|z - 3| > |i - 2| - |z - 1 - i| > \sqrt{5} - 1$

Comment: Thanks But I already knew that.I should have specified that I am looking for the geometrical solution.